# ASP.NET MVC View Not posting back to Post method and expecting a parameterless Constructor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I am trying to post back some data using a viewmodel i have created and it works for me for one of the projects.But I am doin this right now

```
public ActionResult Foo(string userkey)
  {
    vm.Value="Xvalue";
    return View(vm);
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult  Foo( MyViewModel vm)
  {
    // process input
    if (inputOK)
      string value=vm.Value
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
    return View();
  }
public class MyViewModel
{
public string Value { get; set; }
public SomeClass newobj {get;set;}

}
public class SomeClass
{
   public int id{get;set;}
   public string str{get;set;}
}
```

So it on debugging never goes into the parameter method for Post although on the view i have added a form and a button that submits and the page inherits from the viewmodel.I get an error saying it expects a parameterless constructor how do I fix this ? . I wrote an post method with no parameters and it does go into that method

Comment: Does this code compile? as you have 2 methods with the same signature?

Comment: well i am sorry...actually the first method takes different parameters i have corrected it now..

Comment: glad you fixed the code, please also post your route code and your form tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing is likely happening in the ModelBinder. The Parameterless constructor is expected on the `MyViewModel` class, not the Action.  Make sure your `MyViewModel` has a parameterless constructor.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   // stuff
   public MyViewModel() {}
}
```

Comment: Well, I dont have a constructor in it..I am using the default constructor

Comment: I have posted the viewmodel above now...and actually like on the form where i am using a dropdown list  to get the values of the someclass object that's the problem...I mean i am creating a dropdown list on the Get method and using Model.Dropdownlist on the form and that's where it goes wrong...if i comment that...it goes in the method with parameters..but i dont understand since i have a default constructor.

Comment: @vj SomeClass also has to have a parameterless constructor, too.

Comment: Ya I fixed it actually it was a list that I was creating I have added it to the viewmodel...and i dont create a new one on the get method...so now it works!!..thx for your help !!